# objdump -d of shared library with disassembled with start offset

Tags: shared-libraries, elf, objdump

I would like to disassemble a shared library using
"`objdump -d`" with the possibility to specify the 
*address that it will be mapped in a running system*, 
i.e. 0x06782000.
The code/data addresses shown in the disassembly 
then should be  relative to that address instead of
the default 0.

Comment: For example: objdump -d ... --adjust-vma=0x06782000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As much as I know this:

`objdump -d --adjust-vma=12345`

should work